# Twitter posts rating by maturity level of post

Tags: twitter

After reading information about ESRB Ratings (http://www.esrb.org/ratings/index.jsp) a question came up.

Is there a mechanism or means by which a Twitter post can be "rated" for maturity level, just like video games and movies?

In other words, when someone makes a post that they do not want little children to see (because it contains spicy language) can that person attach a rating (like "this post is rated M for mature audiences only")?

Comment: Someone old enough to use Twitter should be old enough to see and understand "mature" content. As for extremely violent/gore/pornographic content you can report it as spam.

Comment: @André: Likewise, someone old enough to go to a movie theater and pay for a ticket should be old enough to know how to check the movie rating before deciding to purchase the ticket and be exposed to whatever content is in the movie. The key point here is the person has *advance* indication of the content by virtue of the rating. They don't have to wait to be exposed to the "mature" content before deciding whether to look at it.

Comment: **See also**: http://schema.org/isFamilyFriendly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter have an option to [mark your media as containing sensitive content](https://support.twitter.com/groups/56-policies-violations/topics/237-guidelines/articles/20169200-media-settings-and-best-practices):

> When you mark your Tweets as containing media that might be sensitive,
>   users will be required to click through a warning message before media
>   is displayed to them. For users who have opted in to seeing possibly
>   sensitive media, they will see your images without a warning.

It seems to only apply to images/videos. Posts that are abusive or exploitative to children can be reported, but I can't find anything way for users to mark their own text posts as sensitive.